# How I get the song of image using MediaPicker iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want the image with songs when I use MediaPicker.

Code:

```
 NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:mediaItemCollection.items];
for (int i =0; i<=[arr count]-1; i++) {
    MPMediaItem *selectedSong = [[mediaItemCollection items] objectAtIndex:i];

    titleString = [selectedSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
}
```

`titleString` is my array.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItemArtwork_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008212 pls check it

Comment: check the documentation for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:mediaItemCollection.items];

for (int i =0; i<=[arr count]-1; i++) {
    MPMediaItem *selectedSong = [[mediaItemCollection items] objectAtIndex:i];

    titleString = [selectedSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];

    MPMediaItemArtwork *artWorkItem = [selectedSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
    UIImage *coverImage = NULL;

    if(artWorkItem)
         coverImage = [artWorkItem imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];

    if(coverImage)
        myImageView.image = coverImage;
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"No album Artwork!!!");
        myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default"];
    }
}
```